# Dynamically loading assets with require() that might not exist in webpack + VueJS

Tags: javascript, cordova, webpack, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to load images dynamically which may or may not exist.

In this case, crypto-currency icons using their 3 letter symbol. I have a few hundred in .svg format in my statics library and when I pull data from a price server I try to match up the icons I have with the symbols coming from the server and to serve a fallback image if I don't have the asset.

In my index.vue I can get away with this code and everything works fine:

```html
<img :src="'statics/icons/svg/' + coin.symbol + '.svg'" v-img-fallback="'statics/icons/svg/fallback.svg'"/>
```

However in a subcomponent that opens if a user clicks a coin the same code will fail to load both the primary and fallback images. I've tried numerous ways but the only way to get an image to load from my subcomponent is to either hard code it like this:

```html
<img src="statics/icons/svg/btc.svg"/>
```

Which is impossible for me as I need the modal to be dynamically generated for any possible coin...

Or using require() like this:

```html
<img :src="imageSrc" v-img-fallback="require('../statics/icons/svg/fallback.svg')"/>
```

```js
// Computed:
imageSrc () {
  if (this.coinData.symbol) {
     return require('../statics/icons/svg/' + this.coinData.symbol + '.svg')
  }
}
```

However this crashes my app if `require()` looks for an asset that doesn't exist. I need a method that fails gracefully so that the `v-img-fallback` can detect it and supply the fallback.

I've tried doing something like `return require(image1) || require(fallback)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common request and latest WebPack, AFAIK (and I just searched for it again), does not expose an API for especifically testing the existence of a module.

In other words, you'd have to handle the uncertainty of the loading yourself. Example:

```
  computed: {
    imageSrc () {
      if (this.coinData.symbol) {
        try {
          return require('../statics/icons/svg/' + this.coinData.symbol + '.svg')
        } catch (e) {
          if (e.name !== "ModuleNotFoundError") throw e; // handle false-positives
          // in cordova, use the line below instead of the above
          // if (!e.message.startsWith('Cannot find module')) throw e;
          return require('../statics/icons/svg/fallback.svg');
        }
      }
      return require('../statics/icons/svg/fallback.svg');
    }
  }
```

This way I'd argue you wouldn't even need a fallback `src` in the template. You could return it in the computed property itself.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I literally spent days on this bug... Had no idea about try and catch.

I had to modify your code slightly to make it work, I wasn't getting an e.name so your `throw e` would never catch. Maybe something to do with cordova?

I just took it out completely as I've yet to see any false positives happen, not even sure what that means. But you could replace that line with this and it keeps the spirit of your code and solves my problem

`if (e.name !== "ModuleNotFoundError") throw e;`

Comment: Yes, definitely. By "false-positive" I mean any other error that is not the expected "Module Not Found". For example, any other crazy error with webpack, you could be swallowing it mistaking it for a "Module Not Found" whereas it is something else. But yes, it is a rare occasion. And, yes too, cordova probably does have something to do with it.

Comment: I miss-typed my last comment and it won't let me edit it, for anyone looking in the future it was

`if (!e.message.startsWith('Cannot find module')) throw e`

Comment: Great, thank you. I have added as a comment to the answer!